# Showing irreducible submodule is isomorphic to summand

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{C}G$-module and assume
$$V \simeq V_1 \oplus \dots \oplus V_n,$$
where the $V_i$ are irreducible.

 Let $W$ be an irreducible submodule of $V$.

 I would like to show that $W$ is isomorphic to one of the $V_i$'s

 I know that any representation can be decomposed into irreducible ones, but I am not sure how to show that any irreducible submodule is of this form.

Comment: Consider the projections $V \to V_i$ and note that their restrictions to $W$ are either trivial or an isomorphism (Schur's Lemma). But since the sum of of all these projections is an isomorphism, at least one of the restricted projections cannot be trivial.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem contains a proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could view this as a corollary of the Jordan-Hölder theorem.

Since $V$ is clearly semisimple, you can find another decomposition into irreducible submodules with $W$ as a summand.  Both decompositions yield composition series whose factors are isomorphic to the irreducible submodules in the sum.

But Jordan-Hölder says that the factors can be re-ordered so that they pair up into isomorphic pairs.  So, your $W$ is isomorphic to one of the $V_i$'s.